# APNs can push notification

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I use PHP to send message to APNs, and it runs well, but I can't get the message in my iPhone; the following is the PHP code:

```
<?php
 $deviceToken = '740f4707bebcf74f9b7c25d48e3358945f6aa01da5ddb387462c7eaf61bb78ad';
// Put your private key's passphrase here:
 $passphrase = 'abc123456';
// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'My first push test!';
$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);
// Open a connection to the APNS server
//$fp = stream_socket_client(“ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195“, $err,$errstr, 60, //STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);
$fp = stream_socket_client(
'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
$errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
  exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);
  echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;
// Create the payload body
 $body['aps'] = array(
 'alert' => $message,
 'sound' => 'default'
 );
 // Encode the payload as JSON
 $payload = json_encode($body);
 // Build the binary notification
 $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n',strlen($payload)) . $payload;
// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
if (!$result)
 echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
 echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;
// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
 ?>
```

I can get "Connected success" & "Message successfully delivered," but my iPhone can't get the message, so can you help me?

Comment: Have you set up provisioning profiles, App IDs, and configured your app to receive push notifications?

Comment: @AstroCB yes, I have set all things, but I still can't get the message.

Comment: Are you using the correct APNS Device Token?